# using cvScalar in javacv?

Tags: eclipse, javacv

I want to identify unique colours from an image. I use `CvScalar loc =  cvGet2D(img, i, j);`, 
and to check whether the location is red or green I use `CvScalar red = CvScalar.RED;`. 
However, a boolean evaluation never returns true because my image contains shades of red. Is there any way of either modifying `CvScalar` so it ignores shade, or maybe fiddling with the  `loc` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since the slightest bits in the red channel will wreck your (binary) question: 'is it green' ?
you might get better results using some kind of 'distance' here.

taking the l2 norm of each the 'found' and the 'desired' color, like:

sqrt( r*r + b*b + g*g );

and thresholding the diff(to decide if it's 'close enough') might work much nicer

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV stores images in BGR format, so to get the value of the green channel you can use `loc.val(1)` (the second channel), and the get the red channel you can use `loc.val(2)`. These will return numbers in the range [0, 255]. You can then compare the red and green channel pixel values to see if the pixel is more red or green.

However, a better (and faster) approach than looping through each pixel would be to:

1. Split the image into individual red and green channels using `cvSplit`.
2. Use `cvCmp` to compare the red and green channels, generating a binary image where the red channel is greater than the green channel.